# How can I make it so there's no newline between images in this HTML?

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSjGa/)

As you can see in the jsFiddle above, after each image there is a line break before the next element. The other type of element, the cycling text, doesn't do this. How can I change this so that there is no newline after each image? I want it to appear like this (blue boxes represent images, red boxes represent the cycling text element):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`li { display: inline-block; }` should sort it.

Answer (score 0):

You use `li` elements which by default have this behaviour.

But for some elements you add a class to the `li` named `text-cycler` and the css for these is

```
ul.images li.text-cycler {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

the float left is what causes those to be stacked one next to the other. but the `li` with images do not have this class so they are not floated left.